# Why is the P(A'|AUB) = P(B)

Tags: probability, statistics

I don't understand how P(A'|AUB) = P(B).

Can someone explain in simple terms why or how this is so? As well as the math behind this.

Here is the context:

P(A)=0.3

P(B)=0.4

P(AB)=0.2

In the solution it says, P(AUB)=0.5 (makes sense).

Then it says:

P(A'∩(AUB))=P(A'|AUB)*P(AUB)

P(A'|AUB) = P(B)

Therefore:

P(A'∩(AUB))= P(B)*P(AUB)

P(A'∩(AUB))= (0.4)*(0.5) =0.2

Comment: Do you have that statement right? As stated, it isn't true. For example if $B=\Omega$ is the entire sample space, then the assertion is that $P(A')=1$ for any $A$.

Comment: I don't think this is true. What if $B$ is empty? What if $B = A$? Are you sure you have stated the question correctly? Please [edit] to clarify (don't answer in a comment).

Comment: Please define all objects in the correct order. (So what are those $P,A,B$? In which framework do they live? Which is the definition of the conditional probability, what is $A'$, the complement w.r.t. what?) Please also show the own efforts to go at least one step in the direction of an answer. (For instance using the definition of the conditional probability...)

Comment: @EthanBolker If $A$ is nonempty and $B$ is empty, isn't it true? The statement is true, I think, if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @79037662 independence... ?!

Comment: @dan_fulea ...I meant to say mutually exclusive and also exhaustive, but I guess the statement is trivial in that case.

Comment: @79037662 Yes, true when $B$ is empty - but not when $B$ is the whole sample space.

Comment: I have edited the question, should make more sense now. sorry

Comment: Are you sure it's right? $P( A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = 0.6 \ne 0.5$.

Comment: @EthanBolker sorry yeah (ab)=0.2 not 0.1

Comment: @Certainlynotadog that is a forward implication, but not a reverse implication.  There is no reason to have believed that the probability above simplifies to $P(B)$.  It doesn't, and grand_chat's counterexample is a clear and immediate way of seeing that it must be wrong.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog No. Suppose $B$ is a certainty? The answer to this question must depend on some particulars about the $A$ and $B$, as in the edited question.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog but we are told in the stated context that $P(AB)=0.2$, so we know for a fact that $A$ and $B$ are *not* mutually exclusive, neither are $A'$ and $A\cup B$ for that matter.  This is ignoring the validity of your unfounded claim, which I doubt to be true as well.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Suppose $B$ is "roll a $1$" and $A$ is "roll an even number"?

Comment: It indeed is purely based on my intuition after thinking about it for only a few seconds. I guess my comments then are not relevant to this particular problem.

Comment: It indeed seems I was wrong. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is in general *not* true.

It happens to be true for this very specific case with these specific numbers as a fluke and nothing more.

We are told that $P(A)=0.3, P(B)=0.4,P(A\cap B)=0.2$ from which we learn that $P(A\cup B)=0.3+0.4-0.2=0.5$

Now, from here, let us find $P(A'\mid A\cup B)$

To accomplish this correctly, we approach directly from definition:

$P(A'\mid A\cup B) = \dfrac{P(A'\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)} = \dfrac{P((A'\cap A)\cup (A'\cap B))}{P(A\cup B)} = \dfrac{P(\emptyset \cup (A'\cap B))}{P(A\cup B)}$

$=\dfrac{P(A'\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)} = \dfrac{P(B)-P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)} = \dfrac{0.4-0.2}{0.5}=\dfrac{0.2}{0.5}=0.4$

---

This is, as mentioned, not true in general.  For a quick counterexample to the claim, @grand_chat provides a great counterexample in the comments above.  Consider when $B$ is the sure event where $P(B)=1$.  This would have suggested that regardless the value of $A$ you would have $P(A'\mid A\cup B)$ which remembering that $B$ is the sure event simplifies to $P(A')$ would be equal to $1$ regardless what $A$ was.

For the claim to have been true, by stopping in the above work just before plugging in the values and cross multiplying, we would have required that:

$P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A\cup B)$

Or, rearranging, that $P(B)(1-P(A\cup B))=P(A\cap B)$, or rather $1-P(A\cup B) = P(A\mid B)$, something that I don't expect simplifies in a nice way any further and does not suggest any nice or common interaction between the events $A$ and $B$ such as mutual exclusivity, independence, or similar.